# Discrete math: sets and subsets?

Tags: set, discrete-mathematics

I am trying to clear something up with subsets.
Say I have this setup:

A={x,y}  B={a,b,c,{x,y}}

I understand that:
x is not a member of B.
A is a member of B

But now I am wondering:
Is A a proper subset of B?
If it's not, is it because A is considered an element in B and not a set? Would it only be a subset of B if B={a,b, c, {{x,y}}} (and in this case, would {x,y} not be a member of B)?

If it is a proper subset of B, then why?

Comment: This question is better suited for [Mathematics](http://math.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about mathematics, not programming.

Answer (score 1):

A is not a proper subset of B because A contains members that B does not — x and y. A would be a proper subset if it were {{x, y}}.

Answer (score 1):

Per Definition:

> The set A is a subset of the set B, denoted A ⊆ B, if every
> element of A is also an element of B

Or more formal:

> A ⊆ B := ∀x (x ∈ A → x ∈ B).

In your Case:

Since x and y are not elements of B, A is no subset of B.

If (as @Tommy commented) A = {{x,y}}, A would be a subset of B since all elements of A (namely {x, y}) are also Element of B

Comment: To possible reviewers: this is a valid answer to a blatantly off-topic question. Please consider reviewing the question, too.